# Convert date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I have 'dob' field that is varchar type and the data is '12/07/1988' and '10/30/1988' inside my database.

I want to filter the record base on 'dob' date range.My input date range is '01/01/1988' and '31/12/1988' but all others record also come out.

This is my code,anyone can help?

```
    SELECT
        dob
    FROM
        `tblcustomers`
    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dob, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y") >= '01/01/1988' 
    AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dob, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y") <= '31/12/1988';
```

Thank you.

Comment: firstly use correct date format for sql date that is yyyy-mm-dd ,and stop using varchar use date instead then it will work

Answer (score 1):

try it...

```
SELECT dob FROM tblcustomers where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') between '1988-01-01' and '1988-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use DATE/DATETIME than VARCHAR, otherwise it will waste time converting string to date all the time when you have queries.

You can simply change your dob field to DATE

and then filter the record like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblcustomers WHERE dob BETWEEN '1988-01-01' AND '1988-12-31'
```

*Notice: When using BETWEEN...AND, '1988-01-01' & '1988-12-31' will not included*

so you may decrease the start-day 1 day and increase the end-day 1 day
it may look like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblcustomers WHERE dob BETWEEN '1987-12-31' AND '1989-01-01'
```

or easier way similar to what you have done, this one is also possible

```
SELECT * FROM tblcustomers WHERE dob >= '1988-01-01' AND dob <= '1988-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Date range will work on sql date type not on varchar ,so first change it to date type and insert date in format yyyy-mm-dd then you can use range it will work

Comment: but the previous record was using mm/dd/yyyy format,so means there is no other ways except change to date type?

Comment: try STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope it will help you.

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('01/01/1988'));
$to_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('31/12/1988'));

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomers WHERE from_date >= '".$from_date."' AND to_date <= '".$to_date."'";
```